# How to set the size of an outline like listview, spinner etc.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a layout with a `TexView` and a `ListView`. The `ListView` fills the entire page in the emulator. When I reduce the dimensions of the `ListView`, it doesn't seem to work. Please refer to this image:

[image]

It's the one on the right. It occupies the entire yellow portion. How can I change its size in the properties?

this is .xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FourthActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/lightskyblue"
    android:entries="@array/Cities"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:visibility="visible" >

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up your ListView inside a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Set the ListView width/height to 'fill_parent' and then resize the container layout accordingly.

Try using this 2 column layout (change the width, height, and weight attributes of the inner LinearLayouts to suit your needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context=".FourthActivity"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="2"
          android:baselineAligned="false">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/first_column"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/second_column"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/lightskyblue"
                    android:entries="@array/Cities"
                    android:overScrollMode="always"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, no matter how I set the w/h to fill or wrap characters, it refuses to resize the container. as if it loves to occupy the whole space. what's matter?

Comment: I add it. pls check up.

Comment: @Renato, as I said above, it can not do the trick even if I use 6 combinations with w/h. and so do when I delete the textview item.

Comment: If I wish to get score, I can select an answer, but that would misguid others. I decide to leave for answer.